# Filter based on days of the week in a PHP foreach

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, strtotime

I am getting from Facebook Graph API the last 3 months page views information from all the accounts that I am admin with the following method:

```
$since_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 months'));
$until_date = date('Y-m-d');
$page_views = $facebook->api('/' . $account['id'] . '/insights/page_views?since=' . $since_date . '&until=' . $until_date . '','GET');
```

After that I am using a php foreach loop (actually two) to get the desired information (page views and the date) in a required format (an array) like this:

```
foreach ($page_views['data'] as $page_view) {
    $i = 0;
    $len = count($page_view['values']);
    foreach($page_view['values'] as $key => $page_view_values) {
        $end_time = strval($page_view_values['end_time']);
        $value = intval($page_view_values['value']);
        echo '[\'' . substr($end_time, 0, -14) . '\', ' . $value . ']';
        if ($i == $len - 1) {
            continue;
        } else {
            echo ', ';
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Which output for further needs the following array:

```
(.....],['2013-04-02', 21], ['2013-04-03', 7], ['2013-04-04', 2], ['2013-04-05', 0], ['2013-04-06', 2], ['2013-04-07', 3], ['2013-04-08', 1], ['2013-04-09', 2], ['2013-04-10', 5], ['2013-04-11', 1], ['2013-04-12', 11], ['2013-04-13', 0],[.....)
```

All is working like it should, with the above array. I render a very nice chart but I want to filter it if I could based on days of the week. For exemple: I want an array like the one above with only the dates from Monday or Tuesday and so on... I need to filter somewhere in the second php foreach to return only the days that I want but how? What condition is used for this kind of needs? Or I should use other method, for example, query something else from the Facebook Graph Api? Any guidance is more than welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place I want to thank you all for the prompt replies, it was a great help received and I am very grateful for it. Based on your guidelines I solve my "issue" in the following manner:

```
$since_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 months'));
$until_date = date('Y-m-d');
$page_views = $facebook->api('/' . $account['id'] . '/insights/page_views?since=' . $since_date . '&until=' . $until_date . '','GET');
    foreach ($page_views['data'] as $page_view) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach($page_view['values'] as $key => $page_view_values) {
            $end_time = strval($page_view_values['end_time']);
            $ds = substr($end_time, 0, -14);
            $value = intval($page_view_values['value']);
            if (date('N', strtotime($ds)) != 1) {
                continue;
            } else {
                if ($i==1) {
                    echo ', ';
                }
                $i=1;
                echo '[\'' . $ds . '\', ' . $value . ']';
            }
        }
    }
```

I can do this for every day of the week by using `date('N', strtotime($ds))` for the corresponding number of the day. I receive the array that I want but if I can, i want to know if is possible to sum the numbers in the variables called `$page_view_values['value']` (i want to make a comparison between the days in the week).

Answer (score 0):

You could do for example a switch case based on the 3-letter code of the week day, and do something like this for each day:

```
$tempDate = '2012-07-10';
echo date('D', strtotime( $tempDate));
```

It will output: **Tue**

This will allow you to filter by the week day. For example, you would only add to the array if the weekday code is Tue. All others will be skipped.

Added @arraintxo note:

```
date('N', strtotime($tempDate))
```

would return a numeric value of the week day (1 to 7, 1 being Monday and 7 Sunday), easier to compare.

Comment: date('N', strtotime($tempDate)) would return a numeric value of the week day (1 to 7, 1 being Monday and 7 Sunday), easier to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something similar to the current reply, with slight adjustments:

```
$first=false; $cache=array(); $conv=new \Date('2000-01-01T00:00:00Z');
foreach ($page_views['data'] as $page_view) {
  foreach($page_view['values'] as $key => $page_view_values) {
    $end_time = strval($page_view_values['end_time']);
    $ds=substr($end_time, 0, -14);
    $value = intval($page_view_values['value']);
    if(!isset($cache[$ds])
      $cache[$ds]=(int)$conv->modify($ds)->format('N');
    if($first){ echo ', '; $first=false; }
    echo '[\'' . $ds . '\', ' . $value . ', '.$cache[$ds].']';
  }
}
```

The day indices are now present as the third items of the arrays. Notice 1: a cache is used so that you look up every date only once. Notice 2: using a bool to not add leading separators is much cheaper than counting down from a count which is in turn cheaper than counting up to a count (what you did in the first place). Notice 3: This modifies the $conv object again and again, because I don't like creating many objects, and this ought to perform at least as well as the procedural style (date() and strtotime()).